# fibonacci sequence function with lru_cache doesn't show all fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, fibonacci, memoization, functools

I have this function that can print large lists of numbers from fibonacci sequence. but it is pretty slow due to recursion. so I found out about the lru_cache. but it doesn't start the sequence from 1. In this example, from 1 to 501, it starts printing numbers from 352 to 500. Can you tell me why?

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1 :
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    elif n > 2:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

for i in range(1,501):
    print(i, '::', fibonacci(i))
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, for me it printed everything from 1 to 500. Maybe your console is not showing everything? Have you tried smaller ranges?

Comment: I am using CMD for this . it works for smaller numbers . but what if I need a larger list ..

Comment: Your program should be fine. Try writing a file. Or `append` the values to the back of a list. That way you should be able to access all 500 values.

Comment: you know what . that might be the problem . the terminal I am using . thanks